# Prevent user from modifying directory structure OS X 10.10

Tags: objective-c, macos, finder

I have an OS X 10.10 application that is a glorified copy utility. These copies are often performed on entire volumes, or large subsets there of. These copies can take a very long time due to their size, and so I want to ensure that the user does not have access to do certain operations during the copy.

Essentially, I want my application to do what finder already does. If you copy a folder from A to B in finder, renaming either structure will not be allowed until the operation is complete. I am looking to provide this same safeguard programmatically.  I want to prevent a directory structure from being altered. i.e., if a user is copying from drive A to drive B, I want to ensure that no folder or file within either drive / structure can be renamed via finder while I am using those structures in my application.

While I am aware that a user simply shouldn't do something so stupid... We all know we can't rely on our users to make smart decisions. That's why as engineers we get paid to protect them from themselves.

Through my research, chflags have caught my interest... specifically the uappend flag. Will flagging the root directory structure with that flag perform my desired behavior? If not, how can I implement this desired behavior?

Comment: Before mucking around with `chflags()`, try [`NSFileCoordinator`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileCoordinators/FileCoordinators.html).

Comment: Looking at documentation, that looks like it could quite possibly be what I need. I will attempt implementing and update this post with my findings.

Comment: @JonW Did you find a solution, can you share what you found out?

Comment: @Joey - wasn't notified that you ever commented for some reason but the short answer is no. Was eating more time than the solution was worth unfortunately.